# Telling the script to wait until button is clickable?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing a script in Selenium (Python) and I am having an issue with a disabled clicked Button. The button becomes active only when the form is completed.

```
<button type="submit" class="pm_button primary large humanVerification-completeSetup-create" ng-disabled="model.emailCodeVerification === '' &amp;&amp; model.captcha_token === false &amp;&amp; model.smsCodeVerification === ''" translate="" translate-context="Action" disabled="disabled">Complete setup</button>
```

This is the button HTML part. Now the button looks like this:

[Button Image http://prntscr.com/pl4u96](http://prntscr.com/pl4u96)

As you can see, it's not clickable. The button activates only when the captcha or any other type of verification is completed. Now my only request is to detect the Button when it becomes active.

```
<button type="submit" class="pm_button primary large humanVerification-completeSetup-create" ng-disabled="model.emailCodeVerification === '' &amp;&amp; model.captcha_token === false &amp;&amp; model.smsCodeVerification === ''" translate="" translate-context="Action">Complete setup</button>
```

This is the code after the Captcha or another type of verification is completed. 
The part `disabled="disabled"` in the first code line is completely removed when the verification is completed. I genuinely have 0 ideas of how to detect it and I failed on finding a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Induce `WebDriverWait` And wait for `element_to_be_clickable`()

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@class='pm_button primary large humanVerification-completeSetup-create'][text()='Complete setup']"))).click()
```

You need to import followings.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: When you see a question like this that has very likely been asked before, please find a good dup and mark it as a dup unless there's something clearly different or unique about it. Otherwise we end up with hundreds of questions asking the same basic questions.

Comment: @JeffC :Sure I'll make a note.